# compare with headers of column and retrieve with its data in python

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to do is that take one excel file and extract column with categories vise. What I do is this
I extract list of data from excel as list1 and extract only headers as header and i take one basic list and intersection with header. in result I get one category list

list1 is like:

```
[{'Title': 'Asam', 'Description': 'all about', 'Latitude': 47545.0, 'Longitude': 65564.0}]
```

a header is like:

```
['Title', 'Description', 'Latitude', 'Longitude']
```

basic list is like:

```
{'Title','Description'}
```

I want output is like:

```
[{'Title': 'Asam', 'Description': 'all about'}]
```

I get output is like:

```
['Title', 'Description']
```

So, I tried this:

```
def main():
    sheet = open_workbook(filename)
    sheet_names = sheet.sheet_names()
    for s in sheet_names:
        xl_sheet = None
        xl_sheet = sheet.sheet_by_name(s)

        header = [xl_sheet.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in range(xl_sheet.ncols)]
        print(header)

        list_1 = []
        for row_index in range(1, xl_sheet.nrows):
            d = {header[col_index]: xl_sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
                 for col_index in range(xl_sheet.ncols)}
            list_1.append(d)

        print(list_1)

        basic = {'Title','Description', 'Location', 'Info'}
        lst3 = [value for value in header if value in basic]
        print(lst3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create list_3 like this:

```
idx = 0
list_3 = [{value: list_1[idx][value] for value in header if value in basic}]
```